# Base plan - storages concentrated or distributed

Tags: clash-of-clans

Most frequently player's villages get attacked by army of barbarian and archer with at most 2 stars. They take a lot of loot (as my experience). So I wanted to ask that storages should be kept at centre I.e. all storages at centre or they should be distributed through the base?

- when storages are distributed enemy is able to take 1/3rd of available loot.
- when storages are kept at centre than the risk is if an enemy infiltrates there, they are all gone.

Comment: Look at what everyone else does. Centralized is the most popular plan. Use that. If you're always being wiped, you need to layout your defences better or drop down a league or two.

Comment: Currently i am using walking dead th8 plan

Comment: I am not actually being 3starred. But my friends in my circle usually have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read several base building guides that encourage spreading storages out at least somewhat (ie, 3 spaces at least between them), because otherwise they're highly vulnerable to lightning spells.

In addition to this, if you distribute the storages throughout your base, an attacker has to destroy more (or even all) of your defenses in order to take all of your storages.  It's important to make sure you have good air and ground coverage across the entire base for this to work properly, though.

Many times when evaluating a TH7/8 base design, people look at the arrangement of the mortars, ADs, and wizard towers for this reason.  Are they clustered together in the same set of walls?  Are air or ground defenses concentrated along one side of the base, leaving the other open to an attack?  Are any of them grossly underleveled and easy to blitz?

If I find a farming base with the TH exposed and ripe, clustered storages, I'm likely to hit the town hall, get my free star, throw some troops at the collectors or other "easy money" targets, and then lightning the storages for free loot.  The only downside is the cost of the lightning spells - you're trading the elixir for DE or gold in this case.

Storages distributed through the base tend to be closer to the outside, and thus they are individually protected less.  Thus, it might be easier to take a single storage from a distributed base.  Chances are good, though, that if your base is designed well they will be unable to hit them all without trashing your defenses.  This is an expensive and difficult proposition.  By comparison, breaking into the center of the base for a quick strike is far easier.  Not every defense is going to be covering one side of the central vault.

By far, though, the best way to defend your storages is to keep them relatively empty.  Nobody wants to waste forces on a base that doesn't have anything to steal.  Stagger your storage needs - when your lab is empty, stockpile elixir and spend gold on walls, for instance.  This makes your base less inviting, regardless of the layout.

Sometimes, though, you're going to lose resources.  It's kind of luck-of-the-draw if you get matched up against an opponent who has a strong army and is trying to obliterate bases and take their storages.  If you find yourself matched up against tough opponents who can slice through your base like butter, consider dropping trophies a bit so you're (hopefully) less likely to encounter overpowered attackers.

Comment: Yeah so that explains the base storage distribution. Many times when i attack i see such distributed base and available loot is about 1lakh. However after destroying a storage i get about 30k and my army dies while obliterating enemy base.i use barch.

Comment: @Fennekin, yes, [BARCH](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) is a solid strategy - it's important to know what a full collector/storage looks like so you can tell what percentage of the available resources you'll get from hitting one versus the other.

Comment: `and then lightning the storages for free loot` Just make sure you are not attacking Liam Neeson's base ;)